# How to connect mysql remotely from other server

Tags: mysql

I want to host databse at different host than webiste.
How can i connect it remotely.

Which setting i have to make in whm to allow mysql to be connected remotely

Answer (score 1):

http://library.linode.com/databases/mysql/standalone-mysql-server